# Altering increment for x-axis labels in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using pyplot for plotting a graph. In the graph, I see the x-axis labels seem to be a multiple of 5 (ie 0, 5, 10, 15 etc). I would like have the the x-axis values to be labelled as increment of 1 (ie 1, 2, 3, 4 etc). Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MultipleLocator](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator)

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
```

Should do the trick in your case.